# running cron job with sys argument

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a python file that takes in one argument (CSV file). It works when i run the script in the terminal but it gives errors when i run it in cron.

This is the line that i run in the terminal:

```
python nb2.py my_csv_file.csv
```

And here is my code that i am trying to run in cron:

```
42 13 * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/nb/Development/code/nb2.py ~/nb/Development/code/my_csv_file.csv &> /tmp/June_QB_cat.log
```

The error says that it cannot find a sqlite table file which is already in the `code` folder.

Comment: this might just be me, but i typically find it easier to diagnose a problem about someones code when i can actually see it

Comment: suggest including your nb2 file in case my assumptions are incorrect

Comment: Is it that the working directory is wrong?  Try adding `cd ~/nb/Development/code;` or similar to the start of the command, to change the working directory to match the one you're running it in at the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you run the command in the terminal, you're in the ~/nb/Development/code directory already and so your current working directory is that; when you run in it cron, it is not.  I would suggest either doing (in your cron job) `cd ~/nb/Development/code && python nb2.py my_csv_file.csv &> /tmp/logfile.tx`t or doing an `os.chdir("~/nb/Development/code")` as the first step in your code.  (Also, I'd suggest doing /home/username instead of ~ just in case you aren't running cronjob as your username at some point, but given the error you get, that sounds like it's not an issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of a file relative to the current script with

```
import os.path
relative_path = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), "sqlitetable" )
```